# How to reuse phpunit test method in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I have 2 test class and all test run well. But the problem is I don't know how to reuse other test class method. I am sorry am new to Phpunit and I already searching, and I can't find the solution.

```
class A_Test {

    public function create_something_1()
    {
        $this->visit('/a/create')
             ->type('Name','name')
             ->press('Submit')
             ->seeInDatabase('something_1', ['name' => 'Name']);
        $data = \App\Models\Something1::first();

        return $data;
    }

}


class B_Test {

    public function create_something_2()
    {

        // The problem is here, I result of new A_Test always null
        $a = (new A_Test)->create_something_1();

        $this->visit('/b/create')
             ->select($a->id, 'something_1')
             ->type('New Name','name')
             ->press('Submit')
             ->seeInDatabase('something_2', ['name' => 'New Name']);

    }

}
```

so for the B_Test to work, I always copy the method in A_Test class like this

```
class B_Test {

    public function create_something_1()
    {
        $this->visit('/a/create')
             ->type('Name','name')
             ->press('Submit')
             ->seeInDatabase('something_1', ['name' => 'Name']);
        $data = \App\Models\Something1::first();

        return $data;
    }

    public function create_something_2()
    {
        // This is work
        $a = $this->create_something_1();

        $this->visit('/b/create')
             ->select($a->id, 'something_1')
             ->type('New Name','name')
             ->press('Submit')
             ->seeInDatabase('something_2', ['name' => 'New Name']);

    }

}
```

Comment: You are not extending ```TestCase``` class? There's a ```TestCase``` class  there and you can add reusable methods in the ```TestCase.php``` file

Comment: I already extend TestCase, all test works, just need a way to reuse the duplicate code.

Answer (score -1):

In your `tests/TestCase.php` file you can do this:

```
class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    ....
    protected function create_something_resusable()
    {
        $this->visit('/a/create')
             ->type('Name','name')
             ->press('Submit')
             ->seeInDatabase('something_1', ['name' => 'Name']);
        $data = \App\Models\Something1::first();

        return $data;
    }
    ....
}
```

Then all of you tests can call `$this->create_something_resusable()`, but remember to extend the `TestCase` class in all tests.